# Chart layout is distorted when escape from full screen mode

Tags: highcharts

**Actual behaviour**

I have configured the `viewFullscreen` option to see chart in full screen. Chart can be seen in full screen perfectly fine. But when I exit from full screen mode then its layout is distorted.
I found the same issue occurs in the official `Highchart` demo

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic

In my case, id of the container div is not fixed. It is generated dynamically. And my single web page can have multiple chart objects. i.e I can not write `CSS` on `id` or `class`.

Is there any workaround of it?

**Expected behavior**

When exist from the full screen mode, chart should be displayed like previous view.

Comment: In the demo which you provided everything works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/LLExL/

Comment: `When exist from` *exiting*

Comment: Do you have in mind behaviour like is shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d6vsw19g/ ?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I have updated the link in post. Thanks to draw attention to wrong link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. I found the solution from one of the forum of highchart github. By setting the container fixed `height` from `css`, issue has been resolved in my case. And its working well in devices as well.

Thank you!!